# Simple API call with "Bearer" token Authorization using Ajax

Tags: ajax, api, jwt

My problem is that I couldn't fetch data from API using Ajax.

I'm using a JWT token for authentication and when I call the API from Postman, I get the data successfully.

[image]

However, when calling the API using ajax, an ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized) error is detected.
Here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: API_URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    },
    data: {}, 
    success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp)
    }, 
    error: function(error){
    }    
})
```

Also, I get the same error when I copy and use the code snippet generated by POSTMAN.

[image]

I've searched a lot of answers for this and applied them, but it doesn't work for me.

Can someone help with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on line 5... it should be `dataType: 'json'`.

The solution:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: API_URL,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    },
    data: {}, 
    success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp)
    }, 
    error: function(error){
    }    
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: JSONP is a simply trick to overcome XMLHttpRequest same domain policy.